# getting past cyclic dependencies when restoring Postgres database

Tags: postgresql-9.1

My question is re. cyclic dependencies in the db. If the db has a table t1 which has a custom data type d1, then d1 has to exist before t1 can be restored. Similarly, if a view v1 depends on tables t1 and t2, then both tables have to exist before the view can be restored. This creates problem when dumping a complex db an restoring it on another server.

Is there a way (a switch) that allows restoring a dump, but doesn't do any integrity checking until the entire kaboodle is restored?

Answer (score 2):

The `pg_dump` utility *should* take care of this automatically, and generally does; however, a few bugs in dependency tracking have recently been found (and fixed).

- The first thing to do would be to make sure that you are on a [supported major release and on the latest minor (bug-fix) version](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) of whatever major release you are running.
- If you find that you still have the problem, post specifics, so that we can figure out whether you have found a new problem which is not yet fixed, or whether you have lingering dependency mapping problems from before the bug was fixed.  Be sure to show the output of `select version();` as well as the exact error message.